# C# Console Calculator with all input on a one line

Tags: c#, console-application, calculator

I am trying to make a program that is a small console calculator where the input is inserted on a single line in the console. example the input "88+12*7/2" should be translated into a math operation looking like this => "((88+ 12) * 7)/2" and print answer in the console.
I will be grateful if you help me to complete this code...

**I did a part of the project but it only works to do the operator on two numbers**

```
static string Input_User()
{
    string Input_User = Console.ReadLine();
    return Input_User;
}
static void ShowMessage()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your numbers with operation like: 7*7");
}
ShowMessage();
string input_string = Input_User();
int result = PerformCalculation(InputToList(input_string));
Console.WriteLine($"{input_string}={result}");

static string[] InputToList(string input)
{
    string number1 = "";
    string number2 = "";
    string Oprt = "";
    string[] Arithmetic = new string[3];
    int n = 0;
    foreach (char charecter in input)
    {
        int num;
        bool isNumerical = int.TryParse(charecter.ToString(), out num);
        n += 1;
        if (isNumerical)
        {
            number1 += num;
        }
        else
        {
            Oprt = charecter.ToString();
            Arithmetic[0] = number1;
            Arithmetic[1] = Oprt;
            for (int i = n; i <= input.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                number2 += input[i];
            }
            Arithmetic[2] = number2;
        }

    }
    return Arithmetic;
}

static int PerformCalculation(string[] Input)
{
    int result = 0;
    switch (Input[1])
    {
        case "+":
            result = Int32.Parse(Input[0]) + Int32.Parse(Input[2]);
            break;
        case "-":
            result = Int32.Parse(Input[0]) - Int32.Parse(Input[2]);
            break;
        case "*":
            result = Int32.Parse(Input[0]) * Int32.Parse(Input[2]);
            break;
        case "/":
            result = Int32.Parse(Input[0]) / Int32.Parse(Input[2]);
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think a binary tree is the datastructure you're looking for. Here is a youtube video on how to implement it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2KwrmjNIrY

Comment: You want `88+12*7/2` to be translated to `((88+ 12) * 7)/2`? This is not the same...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm

Comment: @Vivendi Actually, `*` has a higher precedence than `+`, so it would be `(88+(12*7)/2`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

If your input would be for example '5 + 5 + 5' it would not work because your function InputToList would do the following

```
InputToList("5+5+5")
-> Return Value ["5","+","5+5"]
```

The function PerformCalculation would now try to parse 5+5 to an Integer, and that's simply not possible.

One Solution would be to use regular expressions to filter and check the input.
Then you could use a binary tree or a linked list in which you insert the numbers and operators.

After this you would be able to iterate over the list/tree and to do multiple operations.